# Удаление ячеек в tableViewController через trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath

Tags: swift, xcode

Суть в том, что у меня xcode ругаться на эту строку tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath.row], with: .automatic), а по другому я, что то не очень понимаю, как можно удалить строку по индексу. А ругается так "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'IndexPath')"

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let place = places[indexPath.row]
   
    let deliteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Удалить") { (_ , _, completionHandler) in
        
        StoregeMagager.deliteObject(place)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath.row], with: .automatic) 
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    let swipe = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deliteAction])
    return swipe
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `deleteRows` принимает массив `[IndexPath]`, поэтому попробуйте

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: да спасибо, ошибка пропала, там row действительно не должно быть на автомате видать написал

Comment: А еще такой вопрос, Учусь работать  с бд конкретной сейчас подвязал к проекту  MongoDB и ситуация такая вот у меня есть массив с ресторанами когда я включаю пк все ок все прогружается, но стоит мне добавить  новый ресторан, закрыть эмулятор и сново открыть, все рестораны исчезают и остается только мой последний, добеленный ресторан, а самое то интересное в папке с Mongo появляется второй файл только с моим рестораном (который я добавил), а старая бд не подтягивается хотя в старой бд есть мой ресторан который я добавлял.

Comment: @Роман этот вопрос лучше задать отдельно, приложив соотвествующий код для воспроизведения проблемы

Comment: Добавил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210367/Проблема-при-работе-mongo-db-realm